How to do slick.js slider with 5 slides in one row?
How to do slick.js slider with 5 slides in one row?
How should look the slider look like:
ibb.co
I use classes to add classes to the last two side slides. That these slides will be smaller.
I Used CSS: transform: scale
My JS code:
on( 'afterChange', function( event, slick, currentSlide ) {

    $( '.slick-slide' ).removeClass( 'side-smaller-left side-smaller-right' );

    var parent = $( '.our_certificates_carousel' );
    parent.find( '.slick-active' ).eq( 0 ).addClass( 'side-smaller-left' );
    parent.find( '.slick-active' ).eq( parent.find( '.slick-active' ).length - 1 ).addClass( 'side-smaller-right' );
} ).on( 'beforeChange', function( event, slick, currentSlide ) {
    // Remove the class from all slides
    $( '.slick-slide' ).removeClass( ' ' );
    var parent = $( '.our_certificates_carousel' );

    parent.find( '.slick-active' ).eq( parent.find( '.slick-active' ).length - 1 ).addClass( 'side-smaller-right' );
} )

But it is still not working properly.
I need Smooth working slider.
Can you please help me figure out how?

Why not slidesPerRow per the docs?
